# Filtro Sqlite como erro no retorno da data com a função strftime

Tags: delphi, sqlite, mobile, data

Olá estou com o erro no seguinte código

```
SELECT L.*, C.DESCRICAO AS CATEGORIA , CASE WHEN L.TIPO_LANCAMENTOS = 'C' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ICONE
FROM LANCAMENTOS L JOIN CATEGORIAS C ON(C.CODIGO = L.COD_CATEGORIA)
WHERE strftime('%m', L.DATA) = '10'
AND strftime('%Y', L.DATA) = '2016'
```

O select funciona perfeitamente já rodei essa query e está correta o problema começa exatamente no where que é de suma importância essa condição para o meu filtro. Acredito que com esse código era para estar trazendo todos os registros do mês 10 e ano de 2016, porém nada acontece. Tentei fazer essa mudança.

```
SELECT L.*, C.DESCRICAO AS CATEGORIA , CASE WHEN L.TIPO_LANCAMENTOS = 'C' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ICONE
FROM LANCAMENTOS L JOIN CATEGORIAS C ON(C.CODIGO = L.COD_CATEGORIA)
WHERE strftime('%m', L.DATA = '10')
AND strftime('%Y', L.DATA = '2016')
```

Alterei a posição do fechamento dos parenteses, porém desse modo ele não executa o filtro e acaba trazendo todos os registros da tabela de todos os meses e de todos os anos e não é isso o que quero. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Se vc montar o SQL assim:  
`SELECT strftime('%m', L.DATA) AS MES, strftime('%Y', L.DATA) AS ANO FROM LANCAMENTOS L JOIN CATEGORIAS C ON(C.CODIGO = L.COD_CATEGORIA)`  
Qual será o retorno?

Comment: Dessa forma não tentei, mas eu preciso trazer todos os campos dessa tabela, a data seria apenas para executar o filtro

Comment: Sim, entendi isso. Mas o retorno do `SQL` nos ajudará a ver como corrigir o filtro. Podes nos informar o resultado desse `SQL` que te sugeri?

Comment: fiz isso que você falou ele retorna NULL nos campos MES e ANO creio que não está conseguindo encontrar os valores

Comment: Aí está o problema... o campo `L.DATA` é do tipo `Date`? Talvez você precise converter o campo para _Data_. Faça mais ou menos assim:  
`strftime('%m', datetime(L.DATA, 'unixepoch'))`

Comment: É DATETIME o campo por isso estou achando estranho não era para acontecer esse erro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48673/discussion-between-andrey-and-alison-paulo).

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim:

```
SELECT L.*, C.DESCRICAO AS CATEGORIA , CASE WHEN L.TIPO_LANCAMENTOS = 'C' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ICONE
FROM LANCAMENTOS L JOIN CATEGORIAS C ON(C.CODIGO = L.COD_CATEGORIA)
WHERE strftime('%m-%Y', L.DATA ) = '10-2016'
```